# C++ inheritance compiler error when using parameter in base class constructor

Tags: c++

This code compiles when i define the constructor for c1 without any input arguments. When i define the constructor to take an input argument, it won't compile.

```
# include "c1.hh"

int main() {
  int b = 1;
  c1 a(b);

  }

# ifndef c1_hh
# define c1_hh
```

c1.hh:

```
# include <iostream>

class c1 {
public: 
  c1(int a);
  ~c1();
};

# endif
```

c1.cc:

```
# include "c1.hh"

c1::c1(int a) {

  std::cout << "c1 init \n";    
  std::cout << a;

}

  c1::~c1() 
  {}
```

c2.hh:

```
# ifndef c2_hh
# define c2_hh

# include "c1.hh"

class c2 : public c1 {

  c2();
  ~c2();

};

# endif
```

c2.cc:

```
# include "c2.hh"    

c2::c2 () {

  std::cout << "c2 init \n";    
}

c2::~c2()  {}
```

Compiler error:

```
c2.cc: In constructor ‘c2::c2()’:
c2.cc:3:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘c1::c1()’
c2.cc:3:9: note: candidates are:
c1.hh:9:3: note: c1::c1(int)
c1.hh:9:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
c1.hh:7:7: note: c1::c1(const c1&)
c1.hh:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Why is it trying to call c1::c1()? It is never called from c2.cc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

When you define `C1::C1(int)` by yourself, the compiler will not generate `C1::C1()` any more for you.

When you define `C2::C2()` , you will need `C1::C1()` by default since it is the parent of `C2` if you did not specify a specific constructor of `C1` in `C2::C2()`.

Answer (score 1):

All constructors of a child class will call one of the parent class's constructors. If you do not explicitly specify which of the superclass's constructors to use, it defaults to the constructor with no arguments.

Here are two examples that would make your code valid:

```
c2::c2 () : c1(5) {
  std::cout << "c2 init \n";    
}
```

or

```
c2::c2 (int a) : c1(a) {
  std::cout << "c2 init \n";    
}
```